# How can I still capture a mouse click after the ComboBox is disabled?

Tags: c#, wpf

When a user selects an option in a combobox, I don't want them to select another until the rest of the process is complete.

```
cmbxTest.isEnabled = false;
```

I've also tried:

```
cmbxTest.isReadOnly = true;
```

But that doesn't appear to do anything; I can still select from the ComboBox.

Disables the ComboBox so this works, but I want to put up a message to the user notifying them of this fact so they don't wonder why they can't select another item from it.

I've tried most of the button events for mouse click, this is an example:

```
        private void cmbxTest_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!cmbxTest.IsEnabled)
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot select another column until this transformation is accepted.");
    }
```

I'm not assuming that isEnabled removed all mouse clicks from the object. Does anyone know how I could still capture a mouse click after the ComboBox is disabled?  I figured I could do a check on SelectedItemChange to see if the process is started then throw a warning at that point.  But I'm curious if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot capture any source of input on a disabled element. As mentioned in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.isenabled?view=netcore-3.1)

> Elements that are not enabled do not participate in hit testing or focus and therefore will not be sources of input events.

You can however either show a tooltip using `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"`.

Or you can wrap your Combobox inside another element or put a mouse down event on an existing parent element and use that to show a message to the user.

```
<Border MouseDown="Border_MouseDown">
    <ComboBox Name="cmbxTest"/>
</Border>

private void Border_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (!cmbxTest.IsEnabled)
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot select another column until this transformation is accepted.");
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: (While the other response works as I was looking for, this is less code to worry about; set it and forget it.)  I didn't even know this existed!

Answer (score 1):

Set the combo box to `IsEditable="False"` and hook the `PreviewMouseDown` event.

```
<ComboBox
    Width="100"
    Height="30" 
    PreviewMouseDown="ComboBox_PreviewMouseDown"
    IsEditable="False">

    <ComboBoxItem Content="Coffee" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Tea" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Orange Juice" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Milk" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Iced Tea" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Mango Shake" />
</ComboBox>

private void ComboBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var combo = sender as ComboBox;
    if (combo == null) return;

    if (!combo.IsEditable)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot select another column until this transformation is accepted.");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

As an added bonus, this approach causes the combo box's tooltip to function, so if you're so inclined, you can avoid the expense of a message box and simply set the tooltip text.